# XeLaTeX после перустановки системы не ставит переносы в кириллице

Tags: linux, latex, fedora

**RFRemix 28**

XeLaTeX после перустановки системы не ставит переносы в кириллице.

Пакеты, всякие Бабел и т.п. вроде всё стоят. Не ругается, а ПДФ получается без переносов в русском тексте. Можно было бы сказать, что texlive-пакета нужного нет, но насколько я знаю, в таком случае выдал бы ошибку.

Пробовал не на одном ТЕХ документе, всё то же.

Может он использует какие-то системные средства для этого?

Так как до этого "всё работало" то можно сделать вывод, что документ в норме, просто не стоит нужного именно системного пакета. Только как узнать какого?

Comment: Очень похоже на то, что форматные файлы для xelatex сделаны без поддержки кириллицы/русского языка. К сожалению, я не знаю, как это сделано в texlive (кажется, у texlive есть графический конфигуратор), а в MikTeX это все можно проверить/сделать из системных настроек `mo`.

Answer (score 2):

Удаление ~/.texlive2017 решило проблему.